# Alternative To DD For Back/Restore Of MBR

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, backup, mbr

I need a program that can backup/restore an MBR so that if I have boot problems related to such I can just restore it. I'm aware that DD can be used for this, but I'm looking for an alternative tool, and if possible something from the default repos.

Comment: Why?  What is wrong with `dd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it yet, but Partimage says it has the ability to restore the mbr from a disk image you've made. However my understanding is that you must backup the disk not just the mbr which isn't what I had in mind.

[image]

For more about partimage: http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page